# How to deal with "Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /" in a server?

Tags: boot, 14.04, disk, bug-reporting, openssh

It seems a little stupid for a operating system this behavior in a SERVER operating system.

The problem is very simple to replicate on Ubuntu Server: **just change the date back in time** and then reboot the system.

The boot process stops at:

```
Errors were found while checking the disk drive for /.
Press F to attempt to fix the errors, I to ignore, S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Ok, it's fine when you have a keyboard front of you... just press F and the life goes on...

The problem is: How to deal with that in a remote server where you're supposed to just access it via SSH? Because SSH server starts AFTER this prompt. In other words, when you change your date to a date back in time, if you reboot, you can't log in anymore. Kind of  stupid...

**Is there a way to definitely disable this "fix" so I can guarantee my reboot is gonna be completed at least enough for my OpenSSH server to start?**

Shouldn't it be considered a bug? OpenSSH is supposed to be alive all the time in a server!

Comment: look at this
[How can I make fsck run non-interactively at boot time?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151025/how-can-i-make-fsck-run-non-interactively-at-boot-time)