# Dualbooting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10: manual fsck repeatedly required on Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, fsck

I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (on a HP Pavillion Touchsmart 15 Notebook PC 15-n090sa, bought in 2014, with a 1 TB HDD). Ubuntu is located on the /dev/sda6 partition. I boot into Ubuntu every day. About once every week, I see the following message:

---

/dev/sda6 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sda6 requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _

---

I enter "fsck /dev/sda6". It then lists a bunch of errors I don't understand. It asks if I want them fixed. I enter "y" for all of them, and things seem to be fixed. I am able to boot up Ubuntu. The only problem is that this happens again and again.

1. Does anyone know what the problem is? Do you think it is a hardware or software problem?
2. Does anyone know what I can do to fix it?

---

Please please please do not mark my question as a duplicate of this:

[fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually)

That post does not contain an answer to my problem ("fsck /dev/sda6" does not permanently fix). It has also been closed because it "attracted low-quality or spam answers".

Comment: Have you installed a Windows driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: Hi heynnema. I don't know. I don't even understand the question really. I'm not a very advanced user. On the Windows side, I have a basic install of Windows 10. I've never gone out of my way to install any extra drivers. If this is an essential issue,  maybe you could tell me how I could determine if I have a Windows driver that allows me to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: `Ext2Fsd` is one such Windows driver. The easiest way to tell if such a driver is installed, is to look/ask if you ever transfer files between Ubuntu and Windows, and if so, how do you do it?

Comment: I have never transferred files between Ubuntu and Windows. I checked, and Ext2Fsd is not installed on Windows. Here is a list of all drivers installed on Windows: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hFg9rgYS4S Do you think one of them is causing a problem?

Comment: The driver list looks fine. Do you shutdown Ubuntu from the menu, or just turn off the computer? Do this command... `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` copy that output to the clipboard, and then paste it into paste.ubuntu.com, and give me the link, and I'll take a look at it..

Comment: Thanks so much. I always shut down Ubuntu by clicking on the power icon on the top right, then "Shut down". Here is the result of that log:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/s6v6bYfqkD/
Sorry, some of the output is in Dutch, because I use Ubuntu in that language.

Comment: No disk errors there... however... lets check the disk SMART data. Open the `Disks` app, select your hard disk, then go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Tests`, take a screenshot of the data portion, post it to imgur.com, and give me the link. Then go back and run the SMART tests.

Comment: Here is the result of the short version of the test: https://imgur.com/a/3auY2L2 Let me know if I've done that right or not, or if you need something else.

Comment: That is amazing, and I can't wait to try it. Must I do these checks and updates from the Windows or Ubuntu side?

Comment: Probably from the Windows side. Let me know how it goes, ok?

Comment: It's not going too well. I will try again soon, but am very busy at work. I'll let you know when I get a chance to try again.

Comment: Take your time. Do it right. What is your current BIOS version, and HDD version, using the commands that I gave you?

Comment: Another user didn't care about errors and asked to get `Y` automatically sent to fsck: https://askubuntu.com/questions/590250/how-to-do-i-force-yes-on-fsck

Comment: You only see the errors 20% of the times when you boot. Are these times you've rebooted out of Windows and then to grub and then into Ubuntu? Or were they times when you have performed a shutdown in Windows, powered off and then started Ubuntu the next day? If a pattern could be established to reproduce the problem it could be helpful.

Comment: @TheBlackCrusader status please

Comment: @heynnema: I used "sudo dmidecode -s bios-version" on the Ubuntu side and got "F.16". I used another command on the Windows side and got "Insyde F.16 13/11/2014". But I have decided to put the BIOS route on ice at the moment, because the Windows side crashes a lot. And apparently the computer will be bricked if it crashes while updating the BIOS.

Comment: @heynnema: I used "sudo lshw -C disk" on the Ubuntu side and got this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/nPgfvQZrCX. I then tried many many many times to run that Seagate firmware update on the Windows side, but it never seemed to work. "sudo lshw -C disk" always gave the same result. I opened up my computer, and found that my HDD looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/tcuEC6T. It looks like it's not Seagate after all, but HGST. I will see now if I can update the firmware. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Sending Y to fsck automatically seems to be a workaround rather than a solution. It's possible that the HDD is failing, and I want to address it.

I rarely boot into Windows. All the times that I get these errors are from when I have performed a shutdown in Ubuntu, powered off, and then started Ubuntu the next day.

Comment: Lets check your hard disk. Maybe there is a problem there. Give me a few minutes to update my answer, and then you can follow it.

Comment: Tell me how/when your Windows crashes. It may all be related. Your disk is kind of old.

Comment: SMART data: https://imgur.com/a/BZ42ZpR.

Results of Extended SMART self-test: https://imgur.com/a/hov0Qlz.

Syslog: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JfjmxCX363.

Comment: Windows crashing: paste.ubuntu.com/p/TmpTxKsYdq I downloaded the WinDFT application and user guide and went to use it. But I can't: Windows crashes every time before I have had a chance to use it.

Comment: @heynnema you have been so kind and patient with all of this. Have you had a chance to take a look at this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I missed your last few comments as they didn't start with @heynnema (that's important for me to get notified). Let me go and look at your log files. I'll be back.

Comment: @TheBlackCrusader Please see Update #2 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: @TheBlackCrusader status please

Comment: @heynnema: 1. I reset the power manager, but I will have to wait some days to see if this affects operation.

Comment: 2. I don't know where to find the disk/disk controller settings. I searched all through the BIOS, and there was nothing. But from the following image, I think it is ATA: https://imgur.com/a/bu5pEN7. Please tell me how to do this if this isn't right. I was able to reset the BIOS to factory defaults, but I will have to wait some days to see if this affects operation.

Comment: 3. I don't know how to perform a memtest. This was part of the GRUB menu but it is not now. I don't know how to do this from a live CD/USB. I can't download from those websites because the programs work in Windows, and my Windows crashes too much. However, I did find some diagnostics in the BIOS. I chose "extended memory test", and after about 1 second, it failed, I think citing the memory module as the problem: https://imgur.com/a/hqKJahB. Please provide more information on how to do a memtest from Ubuntu (if this is important).

Comment: To run memtest, you don't need Windows. Just go to the 2nd link that I gave you, download it, and install it on a USB flash drive. Boot to it and run memtest. Depending on your memory configuration, it may take a few hours... or fail quickly like your internal testing did. Good job!

Comment: See https://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm for instructions on how to build and run the free version.

Comment: Do you know your memory configuration? `sudo lshw -C memory` to find out.

Comment: If we need to replace memory... https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/pavilion-touchsmart-15-n090sa

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema: Result of sudo lshw -C memory: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D35gg79sfb

I was finally able to run the Memtest. It aborted after >10,000 errors, which I assume is very bad.

Memtest86 report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JPxHkNDmqp
Memtest86 full log: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vcjsvzmwwx

Comment: Please see update #4 in my answer. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Status update please.

Comment: @heynnema TEST A: Memory Module 1 in Slot 1. 0 errors after 4 passes. Conclusion: Memory Module 1 and Slot 1 are good.
******
TEST B: Memory Module 2 in Slot 2. Test aborted automatically after >10,000 errors. Conclusion: either Memory Module 2 or Slot 2 is bad.
******
TEST C: Memory Module 2 in Slot 1 (good). Test aborted automatically after >10,000 errors. Conclusion: Memory Module 2 is bad.

Comment: @heynnema: What would you recommend now? Buying a new Memory Module 2? I try not to spend money if I don't have to. I don't use the laptop for gaming or anything really crazy. The most intensive thing I do would be watching Netflix on it. Would it be crazy to try to continue using the laptop using just Memory Module 1?

Comment: Good job! If money is tight, then yes, just remove the bad 4G card, and run with 4G. Check the crucial web link that I gave you, as single 4G cards are only about $25.

Comment: @heynnema: A thousand thanks to you for your patience and expertise throughout all of this. You are a life-saver. I am in your debt.

Comment: @TheBlackCrusader glad I could help. You may need to do `fsck` once more at first reboot, to make sure it's clean, but should be ok after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: Good idea to have good data/file backups before doing this...**

---

Update your BIOS, and your HDD firmware.

To check your BIOS version:

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

<strike>To check your HDD firmware, **try**:</strike>

`sudo lshw -C disk`

Go to [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-pavilion-touchsmart-15-n000-notebook-pc-series/5405518/model/6454630) HP Support web site and download these two files...

[image]

**Update #1:**

- you can't update the HDD firmware, as you don't have a Seagate HDD
- open the `Disks` app, select your HDD, go to the "hamburger" icon, select `SMART Data & Tests`, take a screenshot of the SMART Data and post it on imgur.com for me. Then run the SMART tests.
- open the `terminal` app, and type `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*` and post the output to paste.ubuntu.com for me to look at.
- in Windows, go to https://www.westerndigital.com/support/hgst/internal-drives/mobile-laptop/travelstar-5k1000 and download their WinDFT application, and Users Guide, and run it.

**Update #2:**

First, let me say that you've done and excellent job with your documentation and screenshots and communication. Very helpful.

Second, I've reviewed all of the information, and there appears to be no obvious hard disk problem.

Third, I'm starting to agree with you, that the problem is deeper than we've probed before. I'm concerned about the `CMOS Checksum` error right now. Let's really dig down now. I'll ask you to do some things that may be a little difficult, and if you can't do them, just let me know.

**Note: make sure that you have backups of your important files.**

1. Lets reset the power manager. Remove all power from the laptop, including the AC power and the battery. The battery may be internal, so you'll have to unplug it there. If you'd rather not do this, then skip to step #2. Otherwise, once all power has been removed, hold down the power button for 15 seconds. Then reconnect the battery and AC power, and see if you notice any difference in operation.
2. Lets reset the BIOS to factory default. Turn on the computer and enter the 
   BIOS. First, take note of the disk/disk controller settings... it should read something like RAID/SATA/RST/AHCI/IDE/other. Then find the key that does "reset to default" or "reset to factory specs", select it, then save your settings and continue to boot. Depending on your original settings, the computer may behave slightly differently than before. We may have to go back and manually change some settings if the computer is not fully operable. If it does boot properly, recheck operation.
3. Lastly, lets check your memory. You'll probably find a memtest at either:

   - on the initial GRUB menu
   - when booted to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
   - from a memtest downloaded from...

Go to **http://www.memtest.org** or **https://www.memtest86.com/** (use the second link to get the latest free version), and download/run memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass (4/4) of all the tests to confirm good memory. This may take a while (hours).

**Update #3:**

The internal HP extended memory test failed. There's a memory problem.

**Update #4:**

MemTest86 V8.1 Free (64-bit) confirmed that we have a memory problem. Since you have two 4G memory cards, remove one 4G card (remember which slot you removed it from) and rerun the memory test. Do the same with the other 4G card (also remember which slot it was removed from). If one fails, please place it, by itself, in the OTHER slot and rerun the memory test, as this will eliminate a possible defective memory slot, rather than a bad memory card.

Replacement memory cards can be sized/purchased [here](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/HP-Compaq/pavilion-touchsmart-15-n090sa). Keep in mind that it's best to have two equal size/speed memory cards installed.

**Update #5:**

Memtest confirmed that memory card #2 was defective. We'll remove it for now and just run on the remaining 4G card.