# Automatically force fsck -fy when encountering "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY."

Tags: boot, systemd, initramfs, fsck, headless

I have `FSCKFIX=yes` in `/etc/default/rcS`, however, when I drove down to the site and connected a monitor to this server today, I saw this:

[image: screenshot of the initramfs prompt]

I ran `fsck.ext4 -fy /dev/sda1` and rebooted and now the server is back up and running.

I understand there are situations where just blindly running `fsck -fy` is dangerous and can lead to data loss. However, in my case, this is a physically inaccessible server and all the data is backed up in the cloud. It is paramount that Ubuntu does any and all steps possible to try to get it online.

Is there any way to force Ubuntu to always run `fsck -fy`, even if there are any "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY" problems?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Let me preface this with a disclaimer that if you have regular issues with unclean filesystems, even though you shutdown your system cleanly, you have grave underlying problems and its possible [fsck can do more harm than good](https://serverfault.com/a/786659/291077) !*

AFAIK there is no mechanism for an automatic fsck only if inconsistencies are found.

However, you do an fsck at *every boot* with some kernel parameters.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find the line that says

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
```

and add

```
fsck.mode=force  fsck.repair=yes
```

to the existing things there.

*yes* here should do the same as your `FSCKFIX=yes` in `/etc/default/rcS` or a manual `fsck -fy`. Personally I think `preen` would be safer, but then again it would hang on startup if the disk needs some more fixes that `fsck` does not deem "*safe* " and wants user interaction.

run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update grup and verify it with

```
grep fsck /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

or have a look with an editor in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

If you then reboot, the filesystem should be checked, you can verify the last time it was checked (should be your boot time) with

```
sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/your/device | grep checked
dumpe2fs 1.43.5 (04-Aug-2017)
Last checked:             Sun Feb 18 08:53:31 2018
```

Comment: Do you confirm that this method will prevent the system to switch to busybox on boot in case of "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY"? thanks.

Comment: @Poltergeist yes, it will try to fix it. If it can be fixed by fsck then it will continue to boot.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert. From my understanding, the system shows this busybox terminal on boot to let the user to do the fs check and approve the repair. According to tune2fs documentation, the default option for "fsck.mode" is "auto" (ensures that file system checks are done only when required) and the "fsck.repair" default value is "preen" (will only repair problems that can be safely fixed). So, don't you think the fsck.repair set to "yes" would be enough to avoid blocking the system boot in case problem are detected on the FS. What is your opinion?

Comment: @Poltergeist no, not in this case. It depends. If you only have slight inconsistencies on your disk, then `preen` is enough. But as you can see in the screenshot, it detects problems than are not considered safe to automagically repair and specifically states that running it in `auto` or `preen` mode would result in the same warning and abort. The `yes` part overwrites this and tries to fix it anyway. So you will not be stuck on busybox on boot - **if** the inconsistencies can be repaired by one (manual or forced) fsck run.